# jquery-Mobile -> page shows, but next page doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on a basic page with jquery-mobile.

I currently have 2 pages of data.
HOME = ListView of names
DETAILS = Details of the name

When I first open the page (home), it loads good, and shows a few names.
I click on the FIRST name, (ie: John), and it shows the details for John.
When I click BACK, and click on a NEW NAME, (ie: JANE), it doesn't show anything.

But if I click back to JOHN, it will show his information. I'm not sure what is causing this to NOT load the second time around, perhaps caching?
Any thoughts would be helpful.

**HOME PAGE**

## Home

```
    <div data-role="content">
         <ul id="homeList" data-role="listview"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**DETAILS PAGE**

```
<div id="detailsPage" data-role="page" >
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><h1>Details</h1></div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="details" data-role="listview"></ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

**This is my Javascript for the DETAILS Page**

```
/* JQUERY
-------------------------------------------------------------------- */
$("#detailsPage").live('pageshow', function(event){

    var serviceToLoad = "details.php";
    var pageId        = "#detailsPage";
    var contentId     = "#details";

    // getId from global.js function
    var id = getUrlVars()["id"];

    // Apply the content to the page
    getDetails(contentId, id);
});


/* FUNCTION SET
-------------------------------------------------------------------- */
function getDetails(contentId, id) {

    // Load the JSON
    $.getJSON(serviceUrl + 'details.php?id='+id, function(data) {

        // Remove all content first
        $(contentId + ' li').remove();

        // We only need to grab the 1 result
        var details = data.items[0];
        $(contentId).append('<li><a href="#">' + details.name + '</a></li>\n');

        // Refresh page
        $(contentId).listview('refresh', true);

    });
}
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated, the jQuery-Mobile is very new to me, but looks interesting!

UPDATE:
This is my current working 'location'.
http://apps.stickystudios.ca/www/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your details page is in a separate document from your home page then you can use the options object of `$.mobile.changePage()` to allow the page to be refreshed each time it's visited:

```
$(document).delegate('#home', 'pageinit', function () {
    $('#homeList').find('a').bind('click', function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(this.href, {
            reloadPage : true
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Docs for `$.mobile.changePage()`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/methods.html

### Update

I added this code to your page via my developer console:

```
$(document).delegate('#detailsPage', 'pagehide', function () { $(this).remove(); });
```

Which removes the `#detailsPage` pseudo-page every-time it's navigated away from. The problem you were having was that there were multiple `#detailsPage` elements in the DOM which causes errors.

Comment: Check-out the **update** to my answer, I tried the code on your website and it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I don't see that in my FireBug Console... But it makes sense for sure. thanks again.

Comment: I added it to your page via the console. You can paste code into your console and it will be added to the DOM in the global scope. It's a good way to test code on a document without uploading the whole document.